# Nested inner Activity class in android

Tags: android, android-activity, inner-classes, listactivity, nested-class

Is declaring a class that extends Activity inside another Activity class possible? If it is, how would I register that class in the manifest? Also, is that something that can be reasonably done or is it a bad idea?

I was thinking of something like

```
class ListClass extends ListActivity{

    ...
    ArrayList items;

    class ItemClass extends Activity{

        ...
        Item item;

        @Override
        onCreate(){
            Integer pos = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");
            item = items.get(pos);
        }
    }

    @Override
    onItemClick(int position){

        startActivity(new Intent(this, ItemClass.class).putExtra("pos", position));

    }
}
```

Note the syntax isn't 100% correct obviously, mostly pseudocode.

Comment: I'm trying to think of the best way to give my ItemClass access to the objects in my items ArrayList without a brokering service.

Comment: Keep in mind that Activities can be destroyed at any time (there's even a debug option to force that to happen). Any previous Activity could be destroyed at any time. You can't rely on previous activities. Either pass data through the intent, or through a content provider, or through the shared preferences.

Comment: Good point about the previous activity being killed, didn't really think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. After all, the Android operating system will need to instantiate the Activity if it is started at any point (say, if you start it through an intent), and it's impossible to instantiate an `ItemClass` without a parent `ListClass`.

Remember that each Activity is completely independent and can be started at any point through an intent.

Comment: this is wrong. You can totally do this. See Dustin's answer below.

Comment: @whoabackoff - As a STATIC inner class, sure, but that wasn't asked - that way, you woldn't be able to access "items", which is specifically what the OP asked.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it does work -- it is just another class -- you just need to declare your activity using inner class notation in AndroidManifest.xml:

> <activity android:name=".ListClass$ItemClass"/>

Seems to work fine for me, but perhaps when this question was asked, it wasn't supported in older versions of Android?

Not sure WHY you'd want to do this, but you can.

Comment: @Dustin You might want to encapsulate an activity in a CustomView if it is only every used by that particular view

Comment: The inner class must be static!

Answer (score 1):

I'd also be curious why you'd want to do this.

However, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.  Couldn't you reference it in the AndroidManifest as you normally would as long as both classes are public?  i.e. com.falmarri.ListClass.ItemClass?

Edit: Nevermind, this doesn't work as EboMike pointed out.

Comment: How would the operating system instantiate the ItemClass without the ListClass? It's not a static class.

Comment: Right, and then he won't be able to access ListClass's instance variables which is why he wanted to do it in the first place, so it defeats the purpose.  Turns out it doesn't work for static classes anyway.