# Android activity as inner class

Tags: android, android-activity, inner-classes

I'm trying to declare an Android `Activity` as an inner class. This `Activity` should only be spawned by the containing class and needs access to some of its private methods (Methods I really don't want to make public.). When trying to spawn it though, I get this:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.foo.bar.baz$MyActivity; no empty constructor
```

The activity is properly declared in my manifest. Is this just not possible in Android?

**EDIT**: Some code

```
...
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        // Do stuff that uses the parent class's functions
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!forwardResultToParent(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: create empty constructor in your inner Activity..

Comment: That doesn't work... something like `public MyActivity() { super(); }` or even `public MyActivity() {}` produces the same error.

Comment: May I know why you want `Activity` as an inner class? Perhaps there is a better way to do it. Meanwhile, check [the similar question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054971/nested-inner-activity-class-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: This `Activity` should only be spawned by the containing class, it also needs access to some of the private functions in the containing class. I can make those functions public, but I really don't want to.

Comment: @ronmrdechai instead of doing that why not pass values via intent or implement interfaces if you want to deal with methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of the inner class has a reference to the containing instance of the containing class. You can create an instance of the inner class only from a method (or constructor) of the containing class.

Probably you can make the inner class static. It will be able to access the parent class fields only if you provide an explicit reference, but I think you can live with that.

<strike>You should also consider creating a special package and using package visibility.</strike> (See the 2023 comment below)

Comment: I never liked messing around with package visibility. Declaring it as static did the trick.

Comment: Having package visible activity is giving `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{...} java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<...> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.AppComponentFactory>`