# method OnCreate(bundle) never gets called and application crashes

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to make an application that uses lock screen concepts for which as a dry run I've created an app that locks the screen once the given button is clicked, well I've used the basic concepts nothing new here's my Java code

```
package com.example.gaurav.locknowtest2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends DeviceAdminReceiver{
    public class controller extends Activity{
        DevicePolicyManager dpm;
        ComponentName comname;
        Button b1;
        TextView display;
        public void OnCreate(Bundle xyz){
            super.onCreate(xyz);
            dpm=(DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
            comname=new ComponentName(this,MainActivity.class);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
            display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.xyz);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, comname);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                    display.setText("just to test the method");

                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                        Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            switch (requestCode) {
                case 1:
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        dpm.lockNow();
                    } else {
                        Log.i("DeviceAdminSample", "Administration enable FAILED!");
                    }
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

next up here's my manifest that I think is creating all the problems

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gaurav.locknowtest2" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity$controller"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin_sample" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I need to get this done by this week so please take a look..

Comment: Please post the crash logs.

Comment: `controller` is an inner class that extends `Activity`. I'm not sure if you can do that.

Comment: @PaulBoddington no I am pretty sure you could do that only if it was a static inner class, and even then you have to specify it in the manifest with the $ sign

Comment: @EpicPandaForce You're right, but I had to do a search just to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is case-sensitive, so naming your method

```
public void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
```

is not

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
```

use the `@Override` annotation to ensure that you actually **are overriding a method**.

Also, `public class controller extends Activity {` should be `public static class controller extends Activity {` apart from the fact that as per Java naming conventions, classes should start with a **C**apital letter.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, `@Override` will produce a compile time error if there is no method (with the name you used) that can be overridden.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thnk you it worked, I was just missing the static part

Answer (score 2):

Your method is not written correcrt.

```
public void OnCreate(Bundle xyz){
```

you have a CAPITAL O
it should be like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
}
```

Comment: thats a great find. such simple errors happens to anyone new in java

Comment: Those errors can be avoided by using the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: Yeap, but(!!) if you write the code your self and not copy pasting, that's the best why to learn coding.

Comment: Holy Molly, that really was stupid of me Okay so I've corrected it and still the app's crashing might as well go through the code

Comment: @gaurav21 please mark it as the right answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

A class extending `Activity` cannot be an inner class of another class because the android system needs to be able to create new instances of your `Activity` class without an instance of another class. Your `controller` class is an inner class of `MainActivity` so cannot be instantiated without an instance of `MainActivity`.

See this answer:

[Nested inner Activity class in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054971/nested-inner-activity-class-in-android)

Also, as pointed out by others, you have a typo in `onCreate`. This means that you have made a completely separate method, not overridden `onCreate`. However this doesn't explain why the application crashes. (You can write an `Activity` class that doesn't override `onCreate`, and it works without any exceptions being thrown.)

Comment: Ahh...the link you've shared has comments that suggest one can use it as inner class

Comment: @gaurav21 static nested, but not inner.