# While startActivity() catch error Verify class in Android 9

Tags: java, android

I have two classes

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    class Role extends MyActivity {
        class Customer extends Role {
        }
        class Driver extends Role {
        }
    }
}
```

If I call the `startActivity(getContext(), MainActivity.Role.Customer.class)` method only for the first time after installation, then the application closes, but then it works fine until I reinstall it again! Then I got this error in Android 9 only:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.package.helloer, PID: 11174
java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.package.helloer.activity.Main$Role$Customer that attempts to sub-type erroneous class com.package.helloer.activity.Main$Role (declaration of 'com.package.helloer.activity.Main$Role$Customer' appears in /data/app/com.package.helloer-0jDJJnShdiq2y3F6eUe2NQ==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
```

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054971/nested-inner-activity-class-in-android/9419547